# Sahi error 5xx how can I bypass this error

Tags: sahi

I am getting the following error:

`' The web server threw a 500 Internal Server Error at  Tue Jan 5 00:32:40 CET 2020'`

Without sahi I am able to open the page . How can I bypass this error?

Comment: Have you tried to check the server logs for any error?

Comment: The server is external server so we dont have access to server logs. From console could find only this :DEBUG [2020-01-08 10:57:19.574] - SAHI skip remove Header 'Authorization'
INFO  [2020-01-08 10:57:20.566] - The web server threw a 500 Internal Server Error at Wed Jan 08 10:57:20 UTC 2020.
DEBUG [2020-01-08 10:57:25.474] - SAHI skip remove Header 'Authorization'
DEBUG [2020-01-08 10:57:33.151] - FROM HANDLE RHINO-EXCEPTION:_mouseOver(_link("Table"))